# Prove that set is not definable on $(\mathbb{R},<)$ with parameters.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I need to prove that set $\{x:\sin x\ge\frac{1}{2}\}$ is not definable on $(\mathbb{R},<)$ with parameters.

It is easy to show that above set is not definable without parameters. But how looks procedure when parameters are involved?

Comment: Do you know (and are allowed to use) the fact that $\operatorname{Th}(\mathbb{R}, <)$ has quantifier elimination?

Comment: @Adayah, I do not know that this structure has this property. I guess, would be allowed to use it, if I did prove this before.

Comment: Well $Th(\mathbb{R}, <)$ is essentially DLO, the theory of dense linear orders without endpoints, which has quantifier elimination

Comment: @Max, yeah. I think it is enough for me to be able to justify that $(\mathbb{R},<)$ has quantifier elimination.

Answer (score 3):

There is a much easier approach to this problem than via quantifier elimination - look at **automorphisms** of the structure.

In any structure, every definable set has to be preserved under every automorphism. So our task amounts to showing that for every sequence of parameters $r_1, ..., r_n\in\mathbb{R}$, the set $\{x: \sin(x)\ge{1\over 2}\}$ is *not* preserved by some automorphism of $(\mathbb{R}; <, r_1, ..., r_n)$.

To do this, note that any map $\alpha:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the following properties is an automorphism of $(\mathbb{R}; <, r_1, ..., r_n)$:

- $\alpha(x)=x$ for $x\le\max\{r_1, ..., r_n\}$ (call this maximum "$m$").
- $\alpha\upharpoonright (m, \infty)$ is an order-preserving bijection from $(m, \infty)$ to itself.

Pick $u, v>m$ such that

- $\sin(u)\ge{1\over 2}$,
- $\sin(v)<{1\over 2}$,
- $u>v$ (this isn't essential, it just makes things a bit easier to think about).

(Why do these exist?) We'll be done if you can show that there is an automorphism $\alpha$ of $(\mathbb{R}; <, r_1, ..., r_n)$ such that $\alpha(u)=v$.

So let's think first about the case when $m=0$. Then here's such an $\alpha$:

- For $x\le 0$, $\alpha(x)=x$.
- For $x>0$, $\alpha(x)={vx\over u}$.

It's not hard to check that this has the desired properties.

Now do you see how to generalize this to arbitrary values of $m$?

Comment: Yes, everything is clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First observe that $\operatorname{Th}(\mathbb{R}, <)$ has quantifier elimination. If you know that $\mathrm{DLO}_0$ - the theory of dense linear orders without endpoints, which is complete - has q.e., just note that $(\mathbb{R}, <) \models \mathrm{DLO}_0$.

Now suppose $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is definable with parameters, so there is a formula $\varphi(x, \overline{y})$ and a sequence $\overline{b} = (b_1, \ldots, b_n) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $X = \varphi(\mathbb{R}, \overline{b}) = \{ a \in \mathbb{R} : \mathbb{R} \models \varphi(a, \overline{b}) \}$. From the q.e. we get a quantifier free formula $\psi(x, \overline{y})$ such that $\mathbb{R} \models \varphi(x, \overline{y}) \leftrightarrow \psi(x, \overline{y})$. So clearly $X = \psi(\mathbb{R}, \overline{b})$.

But the family of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ defined with parameters by quantifier free formulas is an algebra of sets generated by the subsets defined by atomic formulas:

$$\begin{align*}
\varphi(x, a) \equiv x < a & \quad \longrightarrow \quad \varphi(\mathbb{R}, a) = (-\infty, a) \\
\varphi(x, b) \equiv b < x & \quad \longrightarrow \quad \varphi(\mathbb{R}, b) = (b, \infty) \\
\varphi(x, c) \equiv x = c & \quad \longrightarrow \quad \varphi(\mathbb{R}, c) = \{ c \}
\end{align*}$$

plus trivial ones, like $x=x$ or $a<b$ where $a, b$ are parameters, which always define either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\varnothing$. It's easy to see that the above sets generate exactly finite unions of arbitrary intervals (bounded or not, open or closed from either side) and points. Hence $X = \psi(\mathbb{R}, \overline{b})$ must be a finite union of arbitrary intervals and points, which

$\{ x : \sin x \geqslant \frac{1}{2} \}$

clearly isn't. So that set is not definable.